# Remove {} from MySql input

Tags: mysql, tkinter

I am using a MySql stored procedure, get_list, to populate a ttk.Combobox

```
my_number = tk.StringVar()
cb=ttk.Combobox(top_frame,width=25,textvariable=my_number)
cb['values']=db.get_list()
cb.grid(row=1,column=4)
```

It works fine, except the results are bracketed by `{}`.

RESULTS: `{Smith, John}`

What I want: `Smith, John`

How do I get rid of the beginning and ending `{}`?

Comment: What is the type of data returned by `db.get_list()`? I'm guessing it's a list or tuple rather than a string.

Comment: Get_list is a simple query
        CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_list`()
        BEGIN
        SELECT concat(last_name,', ', first_name) as last_first
         FROM volunteers
         ORDER BY
          last_first;
          END
Being very new at Python, I am not sure about any ot this.

Comment: what does `print(type(db.get_list()))` display? Also, what does `print(db.get_list())` show?

Comment: <class 'list'> AND 
[('Allen, Jamie-2',), ('Anderson, Abbie-1391',), ('Anderson, Marcie-1380',), etc.

Comment: I made the suggested changes, but I am still getting curly  brackets: 
{Biggerstaff, Gwen-1417} etc,

Comment: What suggested changes did you make?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the database query is returning a list of rows, where each row is a list with a single column. What you need for the `values` option is a list of strings.

So, the simple solution is to use a list comprehension to convert each row to a string. Something like this should work:

```
values = [row[0] for row in db.get_list()]
cb['values'] = values
```

Since I can't run your code I can't say for sure. Regardless, the root of the problem is that you're passing a list of lists (or tuples) and tkinter requires a list of strings.

Because internally tkinter uses curly braces for lists, it's adding the curly braces to preserve the nature of the data you're passing in. It's up to you to convert the data you get back from `db.get_list()` into a list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Bryan, I inserted the two line of code you suggested, but I am still getting value surrounded by {}. Lots I don't understand, but I believe, never know for sure, that the MySql procedure is returning a string. Here is the MySQL code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_list`()
BEGIN
    SELECT concat(last_name,', ', first_name) as last_first
      FROM volunteers
    ORDER BY
      last_first;
END


my_number = tk.StringVar()
cb = ttk.Combobox(top_frame, width=25, textvariable=my_number)
values = [row[0] for row in db.get_list()]
cb['values'] = db.get_list()
cb.grid(row=1, column=4)
```

thanks for your persistence.

Comment: the problem is caused by CONCAT. using it causes the the output to be curly braces..{Smith, John}. if it don't use it the results are Smith John.  The comma is missing. Is there a work around this behavier?

Comment: This is how I solved the {} problem.
def fill_combo_box():
    cb_list = list()
    fl = ""
    for i in my_records:
        fl = i[0] + ', ' + i[1] + '-' + str(i[2])
        cb_list.append(fl)
    cb['values'] = cb_list